# Expression of electrostatic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, coordinate-systems

An electrostatic field is characterized by the fact that it depends only by $r$, isn't it? If it is true, I don't understand why this expression, given in cylindrical coordinates,

$${\bf E(r)}=\frac{\alpha}{z^2}{\bf u_r}-2 \frac{\alpha r}{z^3}{\bf u_z} $$

rapresents an electrostatic field.

Comment: The electrostatic fields *due to a single point charge* has spherical symmetry. That doesn't means that the field due to other charge distributions are required to obey the same symmetry.

Comment: @dmckee how can I be sure that an expression rapresents an electrostatic fiel?

Comment: @PhysiXxx your expression is the electrostatic fiel given by a single point charge?

Comment: @sunrise. I deleted my comment because it doesn't refer to general case. But the field of rest charge is also electrostatic, so your expression is also must be right for it. But it doesn't. In general, your expression ignores charge distribution.

Comment: @PhysiXxx ok but if I look to an expression, how can I decide if is an electrostatic field or not?

Comment: @sunrise . Maybe, this expression refer to some geometrical figure with constant charge density. 

It is electrostatic field, because it isn't time-dependence.

Comment: @PhysiXxx have you any idea to know which distribution gives this E?

Comment: Well, I made the mistake calculating divergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [electric field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field#Electrostatic_fields) is said to be *static* if it does not change with time, *i.e.* the the charges that produced that field are stationary. This doesn't imply any constriction on its spatial dependence. In particular, no spherical symmetry is implicit in the definition of electrostatic field, and that field may not depend only on $r$, as your example shows. This is common when you consider examples of field produced by more than one point charge, *e.g.* an [electric dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole):
$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})={3\mathbf{p}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3}\hat{\mathbf{r}}-{\mathbf{p}\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^3}$$
depends on $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{p}$.

Comment: many thanks! You are right, I haven't thought it! And if I would know which charge distribution gives this expression of E, how can I do?

Comment: Well, you can use the differential form of the [Gauss's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Differential_form_2):
$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$ which implies (if I did it right): $\rho=\alpha{6r\over z^4}.$

Comment: Uhm... I forgot a factor $\varepsilon_0$, the vacuum permittivity, at the numerator on the right..! I can't find the *edit* button..!

Comment: wow! :) Probably I have done a mistake because I don't obtain your result for $\rho$...

Comment: Ok, let's check it! In cylindrical coordinate, the gradient operator is $\boldsymbol{\nabla}=\left({\partial\over\partial r},{1\over r}{\partial\over\partial \theta},{\partial\over\partial z}\right),$
where I'm using the (radial, azimuthal, vertical) coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$, right?

Comment: I have found it! I'm so tired! So the $\alpha$ unit of measure is kg, is it right?

Comment: Why kg's? It should deal about electric charges, rather than masses... Well, let's work it out! $\rho$ is a charge density, so it is supposed to be $C/m^3$, where $C$ stands for Coulombs, $m$ for meters and $\varepsilon_0$ is $C^2/N\,m^2$ (recall the [Coulomb's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_law)). Then, equating units in the solution for $\rho$ we get:
${C\over m^3}=\alpha{C^2\over N\,m^5}$
hence $\alpha=N\,m^2/C$. You can check that this result is consistent with the equation for your electric field.
Edit: the actual result for $\rho$ is $\rho=\alpha\varepsilon{6r\over z^4}$

Comment: You are right. I have to shut up this evening and go to sleep immediately!! :) When I wrote my last stupid thing, I was looking at your $\rho$ and I forgot that you have forgotten $\epsilon_0$! A lot of thanks for your patience and kindness!!

Comment: But, anyway, I haven't any justification to have written kg instead of C!!! :D

Comment: @AstoundingJB Please do not use block equations in comments. In the future such comments will be deleted outright.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your advice @dmckee! If needed, I will delete the previous comments and add them to my answer..! @sunrise, you're welcome! ;)